# Delete file from S3 bucket based on metadata?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've tried specifying metadata in parameters passed to `DeleteObjectCommand`, but the file gets deleted whether or not it has the provided metadata...

```
static async deleteFile(req, res) {

        try {
            const key = basename(req.body.key) //file that will be deleted

            const params = {
                Bucket: "my_bucket",
                Key: key,
                Metadata: { userId: req.user._id }
            }

            const data = await s3.send(new DeleteObjectCommand(params))
            return res.send(data)

        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
}
```

I have different user's files in the same bucket and actually want to prevent one app user from deleting files of another user. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a better way to do this, yes not store all files in one bucket, or namespace the key with the users id

Comment: This is not the job of the `DelectObject`, you either need to properly set permissions on the bucket and its object such that a user can only delete their own data, with a set prefix or only with a set name, etc. OR you need to write your own application logic to handle the permission checks yourself.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for your reply! Could you elaborate on namespacing the key?

Comment: @luk2302 Maybe I misunderstood, but I thought that bucket permissions are for different services that will access the bucket, not for end users (the users of the app)? If I set a prefix like `userID/key` when adding files, would that do the job?

Comment: You misunderstood, yes, you grant permissions to entities, whether those entities are services, users, groups, whatever.... See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1 - using `${aws:username}` in your policies may enable some users to only access "their" files.

Comment: @luk2302 IAM seems to be for AWS users. Are you suggesting that I create an aws user for every user who registers with my app? The way I see it is that my app is an aws user (and owner) and object permissions should be handled differently

Comment: Then you need to write the access / permission logic yourself.

Comment: @luk2302 yes, that was my starting point. The idea was to attach metadata to every object or to make a hierarchy like `bucket/userid/object` so that the user wouldn't be able to act outside of their folder. Would that be ok? Thanks for your help, really appreciate it